# Multiple cPanel accounts VS. Single cPanel account

Tags: cpanel

Which of these methods consume less resources (i.e. RAM, CPU, Disk space)?

> Using a single cPanel account with multiple addon domains;

Or,

> Using a cPanel account for each domain.

Comment: I don't think the difference is large either way

Comment: In my point of view the cPanel account per domain approach is more secure and makes easier to monitor each website independently, but I tend to believe it consumes more resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No difference in the amount of resources...*

Almost the same performance because when someone visits one of you sites, the server automatically files up an Apache process, this is no different when using multiple cPanel accounts.

*However...*

cPanel is highly configurable by the top tier administrators and cPanel accounts can have caps in place to stop the account consuming too many resources. Therefore, technically its possible that all sites under one account will consume less resources, but... only because they are restricted in the amount of resources they are given.  However, simply creating more accounts may not up the resources due the fact that WHM can be restricted too.

*Restricted resources will look something like this:*

[image: cpanel with restriction caps]

*Security, Security, Security*

Regardless of performance you should always use multiple cpanel accounts, purely because each account is an additional tier of security. If you host all sites on 1 account, if one gets hack, they all are hacked. With multiple accounts each is jailed in their own little bubble. Sub domains should also be hosted on their own account for security reasons, as many webmasters make this mistake.

Comment: How about disk space usage @simon ?

Comment: By the way I loved the name of your server home directory :)

Comment: hehe, ya, well couldn't reveal my real server details, for security reasons so rather than blocking them out, it was edited out :)

Comment: Sorry but what about disk usage? the I/O restriction or the amount of disk space?

Comment: The amount of disk space, multiple cPanel accounts use more disk space?

Comment: Depends on the setup. If the cpanel accounts were made in WHM then normally you would allocate a set amount, this would deduct the available amount next time you create a new account... For example... If WHM account has 100GB max and you create 3 accounts, each with 30GB, then the next time you create the 4th account, the max he can have is 10GB. Sometimes WHM comes with unlimited, depends on your hosting package. If unlimited then sometimes they use a default account template so when you create a new account its limited, but you can make your own account templates too.

Comment: I see, makes sense. But I'm creating accounts with no disk limit. Forget the size of the website and the size limit of the cPanel account. I believe the cPanel interface itself uses a certain amount of disk space, in this logic, multiple cPanel accounts would use more disk space, right? Sry if I'm being stupid.., @simon

Comment: Yes, cPanel does use disk storage for each account you make AKA user profiles, normally in `/var/cpanel/databases/` but these are generally small and shouldn't be something to worry about...